# Get a reference to a sub array of a reference to an array

Tags: perl

To get a sub array of an array, we can do something like:

```
@x = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
@y = @x[1 .. 4]
```

What I have reference to an array

```
$x = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

What is an easy way to get a reference to a sub array

```
$y = $x->[1 .. 4]; #doesn't work.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
my @x = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
my @y = @x[1..4]
```

is

```
my $x = [ (1,2,3,4,5,6) ];      (Parens can be removed)
my $y = [ @$x[1..4] ];
```

which is basically the same as

```
my @x = (1,2,3,4,5,6);   my $x = \@x;
my @y = @$x[1..4];       my $y = \@y;
```

There's no such thing as a sub array or a reference to one.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that is possible the better way is to take subarray in new array
and then take the reference to that new array.

```
@x = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
@y = @x[1 .. 4];

my $arrf = \@y
print "@$arrf";
```

Answer (score 0):

An array slice isn't a variable, you can't take a reference to it. But if you want a reference to a *new* anonymous array created from a slice of the original array you can do

```
$y = [ @$x[1 .. 4] ];
```

where `@$x[1 .. 4]` slices `@$x` in the same way as `@x[1 .. 4]` slices `@x`, and the
`[ ... ]` operator creates a reference to a new array. The elements of `@$y` are shallow copies of the elements in `@$x`; modifying `@$y` doesn't modify `@$x` (but if some of those elements are references, they will still reference the same data).

Comment: you can get actual aliases with `$y=sub{\@_}->(@$x[1..4])`